# Cannot merge online and local repository

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am new to Git/source control and I followed my book to create a copy of a local repository on bitbucket, clone it to a local folder and merge the folder with my local repository. I am not able to merge the repo despite following all instructions successfully. In the image below, I should be getting `origin/master` per my book. But, I get nothing. How do I fix this ?

Here is the image

[image]

**Book = Git - version control for everyone**

Book instructions for CLI - Make an account on BitBucket and follow the tutorial below.

- Adding a remote origin using CLI mode

Linking or adding a remote origin to your repository (yet another addition to your Git lingo) is a simple process. Fire up your command-line interface and enter the following commands:

```
cd /path/to/your/Workbench/repo
git remote add origin https://your_bitbucket_repo_identity_here/online_
workbench.git
git push -u origin master
```

- Resume your work from anywhere using CLI mode

Now let's enter the second phase, where we would like to resume our work from a remote machine.

There are only three stages involved here.

1. Clone the repository from the server.
   `git clone https://raviepic3@bitbucket.org/raviepic3/online_workbench.git /path/where/you/would/like/the/clone_to_be`
2. Make your changes to the files needed.
3. Add/stage the modifications made in files, commit, and push.

   git add *
   git commit –m 'Your commit message'
   git pull
   git push

Comment: There is a line of code in one of the files. So, I added a java tag for more visibility.

Comment: Your question doesn't have anything to do with Java (regardless of the fact that there is code), so I removed it.

Comment: Could you provide the commands you executed?

Comment: @Makoto - Correct. I only added it so that someone sees it. I doubt if many people track git.

Comment: @sidsmith You might be surprised.

Comment: @Makoto - I did everything thru the GUI. But, I also have the equivalent commands. I will post them soon.

Comment: I'll admit that 11.8K followers pales in comparison to 50K+, but your questions shouldn't be tagged with irrelevant tags.  It makes it harder for the specific experts to find it.

Comment: You can also describe what you did in the GUI. Also, what book are you using?

Comment: Did you get any error messages of any kind?  That would be helpful too.

Comment: @Makoto - Git GUI > local repository (not clone) opened > Remote > fetch from > origin > password = *** > ok > success, but NO message on screen >  close. Then, I do - merge > local merge > tracking branch > `no revision appears` > merge > ERROR: `Invalid revision - no revision selected`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - I added slash and got a big error. Error snippet = `warning: push.default is unset; its implicit value is changing in
Git 2.0 from 'matching' to 'simple'. To squelch this message
and maintain the current behavior after the default changes, use:

  git config --global push.default matching

To squelch this message and adopt the new behavior now, use:

  git config --global push.default simple`